# Use of articles and vocabulary choice for 1970s in Portugal

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palavras, português-europeu, artigos-definidos

Do I need the definite article before these nouns? Is this the correct vocabulary used in Portugal in the seventies? It is a sentence in an English novel I’m writing.

This is my sentence:

> The shopkeeper begins pointing and naming various products. “Sabonete (soap)? Meia calça (panty hose)? Grampos (bobby pins)? Baterias (batteries)? Bolas de naftalina (mothballs)? Cartas de baralho (playing cards)?” And finally, “Fraldas descartáveis (disposable diapers).”

Comment: Let me try if I understood: the shopper will only to say the list:

Sabonete, Meias, Grampos, Baterias....

If it is the case, you do not need definite article.

Comment: Agree, no need for any articles. The fact it is the seventies is irrelevant.

Comment: As far as I know, these words didn't change since the seventies. The only clear difference would be slang words and some accents. E.g. in books from the 50s you might find the pronoum "ele" written with circumflex "êle". Also, disposable nappies exist since the 1940s, but it might be useful to know how common they were in Portugal in the 70s.

Answer (score 2):

If the shopkeeper is just showing their wares (perhaps trying to guess what the customer wants) it would be more natural not to use definite articles. Now you ask for usage in Portugal. Some of the terms you suggest may be used in Brasil, but would be uncommon or not used at all in Portugal:

***Soap. Sabonete*** is fine for soap you use on yourself; for washing clothes it would be *sabão*.

***Pantyhose. Colãs*** (also *collants*) is the word I’m familiar with in Portugal.

***Bobby pins. Ganchos***, not *grampos*, is what we call them in Portugal. Or you could say *ganchos do cabelo* (‘hair ganchos’), as *gancho* generally means ‘hook’. But as the shopkeeper is pointing at them, it may be unnecessary to specify with *do cabelo*.

***Pilhas*** are batteries for radios, torchlights, and the like, which I guess is what you have in mind. *Baterias* are car batteries.

Just ***naftalina*** would sound more natural than *bolas de naftalina* (literally ‘naphthalene balls’). If you wanted to say you want or saw, say, five mothballs, then yes, you'd say *cinco bolas de naftalina*, otherwise you just say *naftalina*.

***Cartas de jogar*** (‘playing cards’) or ***baralhos de cartas*** (‘card decks’) is what we call it in Portugal. In context you’d just say *cartas* or even just *baralhos*.

Now ***fraldas descartáveis*** is what we call it nowadays. My problem is I don’t remember seeing disposable diapers in the 1970s at all, let alone remember what people called them, if and where they used them. I do remember well  washable cloth diapers though; I lived in a small village at the time, and I don’t think people used them there; it might have been different in urban areas. My 2001 dictionary has *fraldas descartáveis* already.

Comment: So is this correct? She’s looking for tampão  higiênico. The grocer points to a sign down the street, Farmácia.

Comment: @Moni, yes, meaning "we don't sell them; look for them at the Farmácia. The spelling in Portugal is *higiénico*, if that's relevant for your story.